# Rescaling Type 1 fonts in entire document, text and math modes

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, scale, type1

A double-struck character set that I like is available in `txmiaX` font which comes with `newtx` package.  I have been trying to move most of my math fonts to OTF versions and the closest I have found to this one is in `Asana-Math.otf`.  Subtly, though, I like the `newtx` double-struck characters better.  I have two questions, actually, and I'll slide the first on in because the second one is the what I would really like an answer for.  First, is there an .otf version of `newtx` math fonts that I am somehow missing?  I have found the `TexGyreTermesX` and `ntxsups` series, but they are missing most of the math characters from the Type 1 fonts.

Second, as it appears that I will need to keep some Type 1 fonts in addition to `mtpro2`, is it possible to rescale them so that, at the very least, all the capitals are the same height?  Explicitly, is it possible to rescale a specific conventional TeX style Type 1 font?  I am using XeTeX to compile with OTF text fonts, `fontspec` with `no-math` option, *no* `unicode-math` loaded, and `mtpro2` for math.

Addendum: I don't think I was clear enough, and I apologize.  When using an OpenType font, two lines are required. For instance:

```
\newfontfamily\stixlower{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[NFSSFamily=stixlower,Script=Math,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\DeclareSymbolFont{sxlw}{TU}{stixlower}{m}{n}
```

The equivalent that I am using for loading the font which provides the second set of characters in David Carlisle's answer below is

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{txmath}{\skewchar \font =127}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{txmath}{m}{n}{<->txmiaX}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ds}{U}{txmath}{m}{n}
```

After this, the usage is the same.  Is there a "Scale" mechanism in the latter nomenclature or a way to modify the former to deal with Type 1 fonts?  I'd like to make these characters available at the correct size from the onset.

Comment: Tex Gyre Termes Math has a full set of math characters, not sure which characters you mean by "but they are missing most of the math characters from the Type 1 fonts" ?

Comment: you can of course scale type 1 and opentype fonts  to any size

Comment: `\DeclareFontShape{U}{txmath}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1.5] txmiaX}{}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. that's what I was looking for.  I knew there had to be syntax available, but I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: `texdoc fontguide` sec 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

newtx provides three styles of blackboard bold, two of which are derived from Opentype fonts, it isn't clear which you want.

XeTeX can of course use opentype directly or type1 via classic TeX tfm metrics, both are scalable formats that can be used at any size.

The double struck in `ntxsym` is very similar to that in `Tex Gyre Termes Math` apart from tighter default sidebearings and thinner horizontal strokes:

The second form comes from the tx fonts and isn't readily available as OpenType as far as I know.

The third form is from stix (stix1, although I compare with stix2 opentype here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


{\font\xb=ntxsym \xb  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

{\font\xb=ntxsym at 11pt \xb A\/B\/C\/D\/E\/F\/G\/H\/I\/J\/K\/L\/M\/N\/O\/P\/Q\/R\/S\/T\/U\/V\/W\/X\/Y\/Z}

{\font\xb=ntxsym \xb\spaceskip=1.8pt A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}

{\font\xc="[texgyretermes-math.otf]" \xc ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ}

\bigskip

{\font\xd=nxlmia \xd ^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d}

\bigskip

{\font\xd=nxlmia \xd ^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da}

{\font\xc="[STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf]" \xc ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I can see where I may have been a bit hyperbolic "most of the math characters...".  Maybe "a significant number of..." would have been better.  As you probably guessed, it is the second of the three in your example that I cannot find an Opentype version for although Asana-Math comes very close.  I actually prefer the third one in your example to `mtpro2`'s sans blackboard font and the first one is very similar to `mtpro2`'s Holey Roman.  The second one is noticeably shorter than `mtpro2`'s Holey Roman.  Can I scale it on declaration somehow?